# Exporting Neo4j to .csv

Tags: csv, neo4j, export, cypher

I need to export some Neo4j nodes and relationships to .csv, in order to import them into another database system. (It's a very large data set).

Is there an out-of-the-box solution, to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_export_to_csv
Yes, that does require installing APOC ... but it is considered as good as "out-of-the-box" :-)

Regards,
Tom